# GWT - Why CSS won't apply on subclass?

Tags: css, gwt

I have a localized version of GWT Anchor class, over which I intend to apply my custom css but it won't work. If I use a regular Anchor class it works.

**CSS**

```
.anchorStyle:link {
    color: #2B80A9;
    text-decoration: underline;
    cursor: auto;
    margin-right: 1%;
}
```

**My LocalizedAnchor**

```
public class LocalizedAnchor extends Anchor implements IsLocalizedWidget {
  public LocalizedAnchor() {}

  public LocalizedAnchor(String localizedText) {
    setLocalizedText(localizedText);
  }

  @Override
  public void setLocalizedText(String text) {
    LocalizationUtil.setLocalizedText(text, this);
  }
}
```

**How I create anchor and apply css**

```
 LocalizedAnchor choiceAnchor = new LocalizedAnchor(choiceLabel.getText());
 choiceAnchor.setStyleName(style.anchorStyle());
```

...and the css won't work.

But if I change

```
LocalizedAnchor choiceAnchor = new LocalizedAnchor(choiceLabel.getText());
```

to

```
LocalizedAnchor choiceAnchor = new Anchor(choiceLabel.getText());
```

CSS works.

Any idea, what I am missing here?

Thanks.

Comment: Just making sure the link you are trying to color hasn't already been visited correct? The [`:link`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:link) selector only applies if the selected anchor hasn't been visuted and you'll need to apply `:visited` to style the anchor tag if you have been to the link before.

Comment: @aug thanks for taking interest in helping me out. Yes, the link is not already visited.

Comment: @EMM: can you check if you are getting the underlying DOM element for `Anchor`?

Comment: @RAS yes, I am. It was my first instinct to do inspect element in chrome to see what happened to my anchor and applied css. Somehow the anchor is having default CSS properties not the one I had provided.

Comment: @EMM: I am asking to check it programmatically. Before you apply new style name, just check whether the underlying DOM element is present or not.

Comment: @RAS I am sorry if I didn't understand your question correctly but how do we check underlying DOM element programatically? and why is that necessary because it works perfectly when I use Anchor instead of the subclass i.e. LocalizedAnchor.

I tried running the application in SuperDevMode and I can see the anchor being initialized before the css gets applied to it, in chrome debug console. It seems the setStyleName() has no effect over this anchor of mine.

Comment: Can you try doing `choiceAnchor.getElement()` before you apply new style to the element & check if underlying DOM element has been created?

Answer (score 0):

**This is not the acceptable answer** but, in case someone is interested in knowing how to make it work.

*I have seen some people (online forum posts) having trouble styling GWT Anchor, so, this might be helpful to them.*

**I am more interested in figuring out why the original CSS is not working.**

> **Workaround**

Update **CSS**

```
a, a:visited, a:hover {
    color: #2B80A9;
    text-decoration: underline;
    cursor: auto;
    margin-right: 1%;
}
```

notice

> a, a:visited, a:hover

instead of

> .anchorStyle:link

Get rid of: `choiceAnchor.setStyleName(style.anchorStyle());` as you have defined your CSS to be applied to the anchor (`a, a:visited, a:hover`) directly so no need to specifically call `setStyleName()`